# How do I resolve Incompatible block pointer types compiler error when returning NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-realtime-database, nsstring

I'm trying to return a variable `fifeScore` with this method, but I keep getting the error:

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'NSString
>   *(^)(FIRDataSnapshot *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull __strong)'

```
+(NSString *)getFifeScoreForUserWithUID:(NSString *)uid {

    FIRDatabaseReference *scoreRef = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Scores"] child:uid];
    [scoreRef observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

        NSString * fifeScore;

        if(snapshot.exists){
            NSString * tempScore = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"fifeScore"];
            fifeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempScore];
        } else {
            fifeScore = @"0";
        }
        return fifeScore;
    }];

}
```

When I comment out the `return` statements the error goes away. This is one of my first attempts writing a method that returns a string. What's the problem here, and how can I resolve the error?

Comment: "What's the problem here": `observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:` is async, and the return value from the method declaration has to be done "directly".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use block in this case.

```
+(void)getFifeScoreForUserWithUID:(NSString *)uid completionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *score))completion {

  FIRDatabaseReference *scoreRef = [[[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"Scores"] child:uid];
  [scoreRef observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

    NSString * fifeScore;

    if(snapshot.exists){
      NSString * tempScore = [snapshot.value objectForKey:@"fifeScore"];
      fifeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tempScore];
    } else {
      fifeScore = @"0";
    }

    if (completion) {
      completion(fifeScore)
    }
  }];
}
```

Usage:

```
[YOUR_CLASS getFifeScoreForUserWithUID:YOUR_UID completionBlock:^(NSString *score) {
  NSLog(@"%@", score);
}];
```